# Validar String numerico

Tags: java, string, validación, integer

Hola estoy intentando validar una cadena para ver si tiene valor númerico pero algo me falla.

```
/**
 * Libro.java
 * Definición de la clase Libro
 * ============================
 *
 * @autor Luis Quesada Romero
 */
package GestionLibreria;

public class Libro { // Clase principal Libro

    // ATRIBUTOS DE OBJETO /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private String estanteria;
    private String balda;
    private String numeroLibro;
    private String codArt = estanteria + balda + numeroLibro;
    private String titulo;
    private int unidadesTotales;

    // ATRIBUTOS DE CLASE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static final int DIGITOS_ESTANTERIA = 3;
    public static final int DIGITOS_BALDA = 2;
    public static final int DIGITOS_NRI_LIBRO = 5;
    public static final int DIGITOS_DC = 2;

    // MÉTODOS PRIVADOS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Método setter Establecemos los abritutos del libro: estanteria, balda y
     * codigoLibro
     *
     * @param CLIBC - Es el código completo del libro que introduce el usuario
     * por teclado en el programa
     */
    public void establecerLibro(String CLIBC) {
        this.estanteria = CLIBC.substring(0, 3);
        this.balda = CLIBC.substring(3, 5);
        this.numeroLibro = CLIBC.substring(5, 11);
    }

    /**
     * Método setter Establecemos el título del libro
     *
     * @param titulo - Es el titulo del libro
     */
    public void establecerTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    // MÉTODO CONSTRUCTOR //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Constuctor de la clase libro
     *
     * @param CLIBC - Es el código completo del libro que introduce el usuario
     * por teclado en el programa
     * @param titulo - Es el titulo del libro
     */
    public Libro(String CLIBC, String titulo) {
        this.establecerLibro(CLIBC);
        this.establecerTitulo(titulo);
    }

    // MËTODOS DE CLASE Y PUBLICOS /////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Calculamos el valor de los digitos de control y nos aseguramos que
     * siempre devuelvan dos digitos.
     *
     * @param estanteria - Estanteria del libro
     * @param balda - Balda del libro
     * @param numeroLibro - Numero del libro
     * @return digitosControl
     */
    public static String calcularDigitosControl(String estanteria, String balda, String numeroLibro) {

        int est = Integer.parseInt(estanteria);
        int bal = Integer.parseInt(balda);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numeroLibro);

        int resto = (est + bal + num) % 99; // Cálculo del resto

        String digitosControl = String.format("%02d", resto); // 2 digitos
        return digitosControl;
    }

    /**
     * Validación de los dígitos de control
     *
     * @param CLIBC
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean validarDigitosControl(String CLIBC) {

        String estanteria = CLIBC.substring(0, 3);
        String balda = CLIBC.substring(3, 5);
        String numeroLibro = CLIBC.substring(5, 10);
        String digitosControl = CLIBC.substring(10, 12);

        int resto = (Integer.parseInt(estanteria) + Integer.parseInt(balda) + Integer.parseInt(numeroLibro)) % 99; // calculo del resto
        String restoCadena = String.format("%02d", resto); // 2 digitos

        System.out.println(digitosControl);
        System.out.println(restoCadena);

        if (digitosControl.equals(restoCadena)) { // evalua si los digitos de control son validos

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Validamos la longuitud y el metodo
     * validacionCaracteres, que nos dice si el string es numérico
     *
     * @param CLIBC - Codigo introducido por el usuario
     * @return Verdadero o falso
     */
    public static boolean validarCLIBC(String CLIBC) {

        if (CLIBC.length() == 12 && validacionCaracteres(CLIBC) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validación si el string es un numero
     *
     * @param CLIBC - Codigo introducido por el usuario
     * @return Devuelve verdadero o falso.
     */
    public static boolean validacionCaracteres(String CLIBC) {

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(CLIBC);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validación del titulo
     *
     * @param titulo - Es el titulo introducido por el usuario
     * @return Verdadero o falso
     */
    public static boolean validarTitulo(String titulo) {

        if (titulo.length() >= 1 && titulo.length() <= 40) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // MÉTODOS DE INTERFAZ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Métodos getter
     */
    public String getEstanteria() {
        return estanteria;
    }

    public String getBalda() {
        return balda;
    }

    public String getNumeroLibro() {
        return numeroLibro;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public int getUnidadesTotales() {
        return unidadesTotales;
    }

    public String getDigitosContro() {
        return calcularDigitosControl(estanteria, balda, numeroLibro);
    }

    public String getCLIB() {
        String CLIBC = estanteria + balda + numeroLibro + calcularDigitosControl(estanteria, balda, numeroLibro);
        return CLIBC;
    }

    /**
     * Método setter para dar de alta los libros
     *
     * @param nuevosLibros - Sera el parametro que introduzca el usuario
     * @throws java.lang.Exception Controla que el stock no sea negativo
     */
    public void altaLibros(int nuevosLibros) throws Exception {
        int librosTotales = this.unidadesTotales + nuevosLibros;
        if (librosTotales > 0) {
            this.unidadesTotales = librosTotales;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La cantidad de libros en Stock no puede estar por debajo de 0");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método setter para establecer unidades de libros depues de venta
     *
     * @param librosVendidos - Unidades de libros vendidas
     * @throws java.lang.Exception - Controla que el stock no sea negativo
     */
    public void ventaLibros(int librosVendidos) throws Exception {
        int librosTotales = this.unidadesTotales - librosVendidos;
        if (librosTotales > 0) {
            this.unidadesTotales = librosTotales;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La cantidad de libros en Stock no puede estar por debajo de 0");
        }
    }

    public void setUnidadesTotales(int unidadesTotales) {
        this.unidadesTotales = unidadesTotales;
    }

} // Fin clase principal Libro

/**
 * GestionLibreria.java
 * Programa para probar la clase Libro
 * ===================================
 *
 * @autor Luis Quesada Romero
 */
package GestionLibreria;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GestionLibreria { // Clase principal GestionLibreria

    // VARIABLES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static String titulo;
    public static String CLIBC;

    // MÉTODOS PRIVADOS Y ESTÁTICOS ////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static String leerTeclado() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader entrada = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
        String dato = br.readLine();
        return dato;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Solicitamos el nombre el libro
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce el título del libro: Max 40 caracteres");
            titulo = leerTeclado();
        } while (Libro.validarTitulo(titulo) != true);

        // Solicitamos el Codigo del libro
        do {
            System.out.println("\nIntroduce el Código Completo del Libro - 12 DIGITOS");
            System.out.println("(3DIG Estanteria - 2DIG Balda - 5DIG Nº Libro - 2DIG Nº Control)");
            CLIBC = leerTeclado();
        } while (Libro.validarCLIBC(CLIBC) != true);
        System.out.println(CLIBC);

    }

} // Fin clase principal GestionLibreria
```

Como veis solicito un codigo de libro y luego valido por un lado la longitud y por otro la validacion de caracteres, pero parece que siempre me lanza false y no sale del bucle do while.

Os dejo el enunciado del ejercicio, llevo desde ayer con el y poco a poco he ido avanzando, pero ya estoy muy atascado.

> Clase GestionLibreria En esta clase realizaremos lo siguiente dentro
>   del método main:
>   1. Solicitar al usuario los siguientes datos: • Titulo del libro (con un máximo de 40 caracteres). Se introducirá por teclado el título
>   del libro, para ello llamaremos al método leerTeclado, explicado mas
>   abajo. A continuación llamará al método Libro.validarTitulo que
>   devolverá true si el título es válido (longitud entre 1 y 40) y
>   false si no lo es. No continuará hasta que sea válido el título. •
>   Código del Libro Completo (CLIBC) es el código del libro completo.
>   Se introducirá por teclado (llamando al método leerTeclado) un
>   String, que será el código completo de 12 caracteres numéricos que
>   estará compuesto por: la estantería (3 caracteres), balda (2
>   caracteres), número del libro (5 caracteres) y 2 dígitos control. El
>   programa deberá asegurarse que el CLIBC sea válido (no continuará
>   hasta que lo sea), mediante la comprobación de: • El formato :12
>   dígitos: 3 dígitos de estantería, 2 dígitos para la balda, 5 para
>   el número de libro y 2 dígitos de control. Para ellos llamaremos al
>   método Libro.validarCLIBC, al que le pasaremos la cadena introducida
>   por teclado y nos dirá si es correcto o no (longitud debe ser 12 y
>   que lo tecleado sea numérico). • Los dígitos de control son
>   válidos. Para comprobar que los dígitos de control sean válidos,
>   tiene que cumplir que sumando: estantería+balda + no libro y
>   dividiendo por 99, cogemos el resto. El resto serán los dígitos de
>   control. Llamaremos al método Libro.validarDigitosControl, al que se
>   le pasa CLIBC y comprueba que los dígitos de control sean correctos.
>   Si el código no es válido, se debería generar una excepción (y por
>   supuesto no almacenar ese código de artículo). No continuará hasta
>   que sea válido CLIBC. Una vez que los datos introducidos sean
>   correctos crearemos el objeto libroActual, pasándole al constructor
>   CLIBC y el título del libro.
>
> 2. Mediante un menú se podrán realizar las siguientes operaciones: 1. Verelcódigodellibrocompleto(CLIBC-CódigoLibro).
>
>    2. Vereltítulodellibro.
>    3. Verlaestantería.
>    4. Ver la balda
>    5. Verelnúmerodellibro(solamenteelnúmerodeartículo,sinalmacénniestantería).
>    6. Ver los dígitos de control del libro.
>    7. Realizaraltasdelibros.Habráquesolicitarportecladolasunidadesquesedeseandardealta.
>         Llamaremos al método altaLibros. Hay que recoger la excepción en
>         caso de que se produzca algún error.
>    8. Realizar ventas de libros. Habrá que solicitar por teclado las unidades que se desean vender. Llamaremos al método ventaLibros. Hay
>         que recoger la excepción en caso de que se produzca algún error.
>    9. Consultar unidades totales.
>    10. Salirdelaaplicación. La visualización del Menu lo introduciremos en un método llamado: visualizarMenu (será privado) Introduciremos
>          una opción llamando al método leerOpcion (explicado después),
>          realizaremos las sentencias para realizar cada una de las opciones y
>          finalmente llamaremos al método pulsarTecla (expicado despúes) , por
>          el cual el programa se parará hasta que pulsemos una tecla. Dentro de
>          la clase GestionLibreia crearemos los siguientes métodos privados y
>          estáticos: o
>          StringleerTeclado():enelquemedianteInputStreamReaderyreadLine,nosdevuelvaunStringconlo
>          tecleado. Pondremos un try-catch y propagaremos la excepción, si
>          salta alguna. o
>          intleerOpcion():métodoporelquellamandoalanteriornosdevuelvaunaopciónválida(entre0y9).
>          Pondremos un try-catch y propagaremos la excepción, si salta
>          NumberFormatException, IOException o cualquier otra. o int
>          pulsarTecla(): método por medio de InputStreamReader y read()
>          pulsaremos una tecla. Pondremos un try-catch y propagaremos la
>          excepción, si salta alguna Clase Libro Esta clase debe proporner
>          todas las herramientas necesarias para almacenar y trabajar con la
>          siguiente información sobre los libros vendidos por una librería •
>          Atributos: o Código del artículo: se almacenará mediante 3
>          atributos: §
>          estateria:estanteríadondeestánalmacenadoellibro(3dígitosnuméricos),
>          almacenado como cadena. §
>          balda:baldadondeestáellibro(2dígitosnuméricos,almacenadocomocadena
>          §
>          numeroLibro:númeroindividualdellibro(5dígitosnuméricos),almacenadocomo
>          cadena. § Losdígitosdecontrolnosealmacenanporquesepuedencalcular. o
>          titulo: título del libro (cadena de 40 caracteres) o unidadesTotales:
>          Unidades totales que hay de ese libro en el almacén (entero de 5
>          caracteres). • Métodos Privados: o establecerLibro: le pasaremos como
>          entrada una cadena con el CLIBC (código de libro completo) y se
>          separarán los 3 atributos: estantería, balda y codigoLibro y los
>          almacenará en los atributos del objeto o establecerTitulo: pasándole
>          como entrada una cadena con el título, comprobará que sea correcta
>          llamando al método validarTitulo y lo almacenará en el atributo
>          titulo.
>          • Contructor: le pasaremos el CLIBC y el título y llamando a los métodos establecerLibro y establecerTitulo, asignará el valor a
>          los atributos. • Constantes: tendremos 4 constantes:
>          DIGITOS_ESTANTERIA, valor 2, DIGITOS_BALDA, valor 3, DIGITOS_NRO_LIBRO
>          valor 5, DIGITOS_DC, valor 2. Se utilizarán donde se necesite. •
>          Métodos estáticos y públicos: o calcularDigitosControl: al que le
>          pasaremos: estantería, balda y codigoLibro y nos devolverá los
>          dígitos de control como cadena. Para calcular los díditos de control
>          sumaremos: estantería+balda + no libro, se divide por 99 y se coge el
>          resto. El resto son los dígitos de control (método estático y
>          público) o validarDigitosControl: le pasaremos como entrada al
>          método un CLIBC y nos devolverá true si los dígitos son correctos y
>          false si no lo son. Para comprobar que los dígitos de control sean
>          válidos, en primer lugar, mediante el método
>          CLIBC.substring(inicio,final), sacaremos de CLIBC: estantería, balda,
>          no libro y los dígitos de control. Sumaremos: estantería+balda + no
>          libro, se divide por 99 y se coge el resto. El resto serán los
>          dígitos de control, que deben coincidir con los dos dígitos de
>          control de CLIBC (método estático y público). Si coinciden,
>          devolverá true, si no coincide false. o validarCLIBC: le pasaremos
>          una cadena CLIBC y nos devolverá true si es correcto (logitud =12 y
>          que sea numérico) y false si no lo es. (método estático y público)
>          o validarTitulo: le pasaremos una cadena con el título del libro y
>          nos devolverá true si el título es válido (longitud entre 1 y 40) y
>          false si no lo es. • Métodos de Interfaz: públicos o Obtener el
>          valor de los atributos: getEstanteria, getBalda, getNumeroLibro,
>          getDigitosControl (Llamará a método calcularDigitosControl) ,
>          getTitulo, getUnidadesTotales, getCLIBC (lo compondrá concatenando la
>          estantería, la balda, el no de libro y lo devuelto por el método
>          calcularDigitosControl. o altaLibros: se le pasa como entrada las
>          unidades y se les sumarán a las unidades totales. Controlaremos que
>          las unidades sean >0, en caso de no serlo levantaremos una excepción.
>          o ventaLibros se le pasa como entrada las unidades y se les restarán
>          a las unidades totales. Controlaremos que las unidades sean > 0 y que
>          sean < que las unidades totales en almacén, en cada caso levantaremos
>          una excepción. • Si crees conveniente introducir algún otro método,
>          justifica su necesidad. Utilizaremos el método
>          Integer.parseInt(String cadena) para convertir una cadena en un
>          entero. El código fuente Java debe incluir comentarios en cada
>          atributo (o en cada conjunto de atributos) y método (o en cada
>          conjunto de métodos del mismo tipo) indicando su utilidad. El
>          programa principal también debería incluir algunos comentarios
>          explicativos sobre su funcionamiento y la utilización de objetos de
>          la clase Libro

Comment: Que estas tratando de validar? que cadena? cuales son las cadenas validas? como es la forma en que lo validas?

Answer (score 2):

Este metodo recorre todo tu String y analiza mediante el codigo ASCII que todos los caracteres del String sean numeros si encuentra alguno te devuel falso:

```
 public static boolean validacionCaracteres(String CLIBC) { 

 for (int i = 0; i < CLIBC.length(); i++) {
        if (CLIBC.charAt(i) - '0' <= 0 && CLIBC.charAt(i) - '0' >= 9) {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

espero te sea de ayuda.Grasias

Comment: por que? como esto soluciona la pregunta? , no estas explicando nada de lo que indicas, favor de editar y argumentar

Comment: He implementado el ciclo for y funciona a la perfección

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes al intentar convertir a `Integer` un número con 12 cifras, lo cual causa una excepción `NumberFormat`

En Java, el tamaño máximo de un tipo entero lo obtienes llamando a `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, para valores positivos es de `2147483647` que como puedes ver solo tiene 10 cifras.

Es por eso que debes usar un bucle `for` como el que plantea @Yoelvis, recorriendo carácter por carácter para verificar si es un número.

En mi caso, yo probaría usando lo que ya tienes implementado con el `try/catch` pero de la siguiente manera:

```
public static boolean validacionCaracteres(String CLIBC) {

    for (int i = 0; i < CLIBC.length(); i++) {
        try {
            String s = String.valueOf(CLIBC.charAt(i));
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;            
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Espero que esto responda tu pregunta incial de porqué siempre daba `false` tu condición.