# Validacion en java

Tags: java

Como puedo validar esto pero en int que solamente logro hacerlo en string (para que el campo no este vacio) mi variable en int es precio y solo puedo con nombre ya que precio es int, gracias

```
private boolean compruebaNombre(){
    if(nombre.equals("")){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podrías tener un int vacío? Por defecto los `int` tienen un valor de 0.

Comment: @Jacobo Implementa regla de negocio código: no puede estar vacío, eso me sale como regla de negocio que  puedes interpretar tú? yo al menos entiendo que si no se da datos a esa variable deberia salir una condición que diga que se rellene nuevamente pero con un valor, no se si yo estoy mal o no entiendo completamente pero am menos eso interpreto

Comment: @Jacobo como en —implementa regla de negocio nombre marca: no puede estar vacío, y como se ve el codigo de arriba ahi realice esa validacion pero no entiendo para hacerlo de tipo int para al menos codigo no se como realizarlo

Comment: @Jacobo y estoy realizando un scanner con un menú el cual contiene arraylist y tengo metodo agregar y necesito implementarlo esa condicion en el set de los accesadores entonces al agregar la persona le saldra un menu que tiene q asignarle valor a la variable codigo y si apreta enter sin agregar nada que no pase no se si se entiende xd, y solo me falta esa validación y termino:(

Comment: Quizá tengas que cambiar el `int` por `Integer` y comprobar que no sea null... pero sin saber cómo se rellena el campo es complicado saberlo. Falta el código que se encarga de obtener los datos de los campos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Validar String numerico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231794/validar-string-numerico)